# pg_log directory for postgresql in ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

I followed instruction on http://pydanny-event-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/DjangoConEurope2012/10-steps-to-better-postgresql-performance.html

it says to set `log_directory = pg_log`

where's that directory in ubuntu? :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under postgres data directory something like `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_log`

Comment: The data directory may be different according to the way Postgres was installed.

Answer (score 12):

The query gives you the actual log directory in any operating system.

```
select format('%s/%s', 
    current_setting('data_directory'),
    current_setting('log_directory'));
```